# Greeting program

Tags: python, eclipse, if-statement, new-operator, pydev

I have been learning how to program in Python using the book "Python the Absolute Beginners Guide." The problem I am having is that when using `eclipse-pydev` it won't allow me to use the `if` statement. Here is the code I have written...

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print(name)
print("Hello" name )
```

The result was

```
What is your name? caleb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/calebmatthias/Document/workspace/de.vogella.python.first/simpprogram.py", line 6, in <module>
    name = input("What is your name? ")
  File "/Users/calebmatthias/Desktop/eclipse 2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.2.3.2011100616/PySrc/pydev_sitecustomize/sitecustomize.py", line 210, in input
    return eval(raw_input(prompt))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'caleb' is not defined
```

When I do my `if` statement I put

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
if name == ("Caleb"):
    print(" Hello Bud!")
```

The result was

```
  What is your name? Caleb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/calebmatthias/Document/workspace/de.vogella.python.first/simpprogram.py", line 6, in <module>
    name = input("What is your name? ")
  File "/Users/calebmatthias/Desktop/eclipse 2/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.2.3.2011100616/PySrc/pydev_sitecustomize/sitecustomize.py", line 210, in input
    return eval(raw_input(prompt))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Caleb' is not defined
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input).

Python developers probably should have renamed those functions so it's more clear and beginners don't get confused so easily.

When you type `caleb` into the prompt with `input` it's trying to evaluate `caleb` which looks like a variable. The variable `caleb` hasn't been defined, so it's raising that exception.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that you are using the `input` function which expects that the user will input a string that can evaluate to a python expression. Try changing it to `raw_input` which will not try to eval, but rather give you a raw string.
Also, try just doing your print statement like: `print "Hello", name`  You were missing a comma sep in that first example.

Comment: He should probably keep the format `print()`, in case he's working with 3.x, but this is right otherwise.

Comment: @TorelTwiddler: I think he needs to add `from __future__ import print_function` to continue using it as a function in Python 2.x. And he needs a comma in there.

Comment: @Mark, Sorry, yeah, keep the comma, but `print('Hello World')` works fine in 2.x (at least 2.6+).

Comment: Actually, now that I play with it again, `print('Hello', 'World')` does not return the same thing as `print 'Hello', 'World'`... I guess clarification on his version is required to decide that =P

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out a newbie!!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> help(input)

input([prompt]) -> value

Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

Use `raw_input`.