# raw_input in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I using the raw_input API in python 2.7

I do:

```
mass_storage_choice = raw_input("Have you enabled USB mass storage on the phone Yes or No?");
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tools\ide\juno\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.3.2013031601\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 765, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\tools\ide\juno\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.3.2013031601\pysrc\pydevd_vars.py", line 376, in evaluateExpression
    result = eval(compiled, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Y' is not defined
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does this error occur before the user types something and submits it, or after? If it occurs afterwards, what did the user type and submit?

Comment: the problem probably is when you're trying to use that `mass_storage_choice` var somewhere, since, as is, your raw_input call works as intended

Comment: possible duplicate of [pydev interactive console and raw\_input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138304/pydev-interactive-console-and-raw-input)

Comment: how sure are you that you do not use `input` or otherwise evaluate the string at some point?

Comment: Show us the entire code, the reason it may be considering as an statement, sine the user input may either be (Y/N) and it complains about `NameError:` on `Y`

Answer (score 0):

In-case you are using an if...then loop in the code make sure you actually put Y in single quotes.Like this 'Y'.Because I am getting a feeling you are processing the Y input which according to me, means yes.Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the input from user pass the input to a variable to be defined that should work.