# Python name error in LInux terminal when the input is defined

Tags: python, linux, input

I am running python 3.6 on Linux. When I use the python shell to test the code, it works as it is supposed to do. However, if run from the linux terminal, I get a name error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Hi")
name = input("What\'s your name?")
print (name, "is a cool name")
```

Then after inputting a name from the linux terminal, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    name = input("What\'s your name?")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Matt' is not defined
```

I know that if run on python 2, you need to use raw input, however this is not used in python 3. Is there another line of code so that the linux terminal accepts it, like `#!/usr`?

Comment: how did you run it ?

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/python --version` give you?

Comment: try: `print '{} is a cool name'.format(name)`

Comment: @syntonym Without it, the linux terminal does not accept it as python code.

Comment: No, i mean what happens if you type `/usr/bin/python --version` into your terminal. It looks like you are running python2, even if you don't intend to.

Comment: to be sure you use python 3 type `python3 test.py`

Comment: It sounds like `/usr/bin/python` is Python 2, not Python 3. How are you running the Python shell?

Comment: @syntonym You're right, for some reason the linux terminal says I am using 2.7, but python says I am running 3.6.2rc1. What happened?

Comment: @matt-333: What happens is that you have both python2 and python3 installed. My guess is that python3 is first in the path so when you run `$ python ` you are running python3, but `/usr/bin/python` is actually python2. You can check where it is with `$ which python` or `$ type python`.

Comment: @matt-333 What do you mean with "python says I'm running 3.6"? How do you execute python if you do that?

Comment: @syntonym I'm just reading off what it says in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line `#!/usr/bin/python` you are telling the system to use Python 2.

In Python 2, you would need to change `input` to `raw_input`, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Hi")
name = raw_input("What\'s your name?")
print(name, "is a cool name")
```

See [Greeting program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747871/greeting-program) for more information.

However, to tell the system to run the script with Python 3, change your shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/python3`, or preferably `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Comment: He says he's using Python 3, it doesn't require `raw_input`.

Comment: @Barmar Excuse me, I missed that part. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run like this: **python3 test.py**